# question about pgf-blur package in xelatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, xetex, shadows

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

\tikzfading[name=fade down,
     top color=transparent!30,
     bottom color=transparent!0]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis x line*=bottom,
             axis y line*=left, blur shadow] 
  \addplot[yshift=-2pt,ybar, blue, fill,path fading=fade down, rounded corners=2pt]
       coordinates{(1,2.9) (2,1.7) (3,4.2) (4,5.1) (5,4) (6,2.2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

when I compile the code use `pdflatex`, the PDF is display correct. but when I compile using `xelatex`, in the generated `pdf`, the shadows became to black color.

why? how to fix it?

[image: pdflatex output]

[image: xelatex output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Which version of PGF are you using?  With the CVS version then I get the same output with xelatex as with pdflatex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def}%%%% the correct driver for xelatex
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
[...]
```