# pgf-blur shadow glitch using different node sizes and XeLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, xetex, shadows, pgf-blur

Here's my MWE:

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}  

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\tikzstyle{blurredShadow} = [rectangle, thick, draw=none, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm, fill=green!50, blur shadow={shadow opacity=40}]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]

\node (one) {Blabla};
\node (two) [right of=one]{
  \begin{tabular}{c}
        Blabla \\
        \& Blublu \\
    \end{tabular}
    };

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node [blurredShadow, above of=one, yshift=-2cm] { };
\node [blurredShadow, above of=two, yshift=-2cm, minimum height=1.5cm] { };
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

gives me this:

[image: pgf-blur glitch]

The glitch does not occur when compiling with pdfLaTeX. However, I need to use XeLaTex because I need to use the fontspec package.

Linux 64bit Ubuntu 16.04.
Tex version: TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)

The following [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110547/question-about-pgf-blur-package-in-xelatex/110552) to a similar problem did not work for me: Define driver by setting`\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def}`

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Seems to be a bug. I can confirm the problem on XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is still present in with an up-to-date xelatex from texlive2017.

Comment: Would using lulatex be a workaround?

Comment: @samcarter not really, my IDE (RStudio) doesn't support lualatex

Comment: @jmjr According to https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200637578/comments/201142038 lualatex might work in rstudio

Comment: @samcarter yeah I saw that post, but I couldn't manage to make it work. The command in that post seems for windows only

Comment: Did you try to create a style with two arguments, `minimum width` and `minimum height`? `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround you can pass the height and width to the style.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}  

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\tikzset{blurredShadow/.style 2 args={rectangle, thick, draw=none, minimum
width=#1, minimum height=#2, fill=green!50, blur shadow={shadow
opacity=40}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]

\node (one) {Blabla};
\node (two) [right of=one]{
  \begin{tabular}{c}
        Blabla \\
        \& Blublu \\
    \end{tabular}
    };

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node [blurredShadow={1.5cm}{1.5cm}, above of=two, yshift=-2cm] { };
\node [blurredShadow={1.5cm}{0.5cm}, above of=one, yshift=-2cm] { };
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me when using XeLaTeX. Did you try with XeLaTeX?

Comment: @jmjr Ooops, sorry! Now better?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Still not working as supposed.

Comment: @jmjr You won't like it, but on my TeXLive 2017 installation the shadows show correctly if I compile with xelatex. That is, I was able to reproduce your output with your original snippet (and with xelatex), but this one shows the appropriate shadows.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I installed texlive 2017 ("vanilla"). Unfortunately shadows are still incorrect (using your code). Do you have any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: @marmot See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445321/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that's clearly better. These questions have been around and other solutions have proposed, but I think yours is better. (And I wrote "temporary workaround" in March, which is also correct. ;-)